# Access token regeneration for Axios requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, ecmascript-8

***Description***

I've developed an application which use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to communicate with the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/). PayPal has a [NodeJS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/#set-up-the-environment), but unfortunately this doesn't support the `Subscription API`, so I'm using `axios` to handle the `API` requests.

The code is working well, but I want improve the `Access Token` logic. Essentially the `PayPal` token expiry is 1 hour, and I don't want to get a new token each time I perform a request.

So I've used a mechanism that allows me to store the token in my own database and through the `interceptors` of `Axios` I retrieve that token. If the token is expired, I get a new one.

***Code***

First of all, I've declared the `axios` instance, I don't want use the global instance 'cause I could reuse `axios` for other `API` payment gateways such as `Stripe`:

```
const qs = require('qs');
const axios = require('axios');
const tokenUtils = require('./token-utils');

const baseURL = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com';

let instance = axios.create({
    baseURL
})
```

then I defined the `interceptors` which is something like a `middleware` and is executed before any request:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(

    // Return response as no errors raised
    function (response) {
        return response
    },

    function (error) {
        const errorResponse = error.response;

        // Check if token is expired
        if (isTokenExpiredError(errorResponse)) {
            return resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error)
        }

        // Error was not generated by the expired token
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)
```

then I have the `isTokenExpiredError` which simply checks if the token is expired looking at the `http` status code:

```
function isTokenExpiredError(errorResponse) {
    return (errorResponse.status == 401) ? true : false;
}
```

Next, I have the `resetTokenAndReattemptRequest` function which actually checks if the token is expired and eventually gets a new one:

```
let isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false;

async function resetTokenAndReattemptRequest(error) {

    try {
        const { response } = error;

        // Get the stored token
        const accessToken = await tokenUtils.getResetToken();

        // Start the token generation task
        // Add the failed request to the subscriber
        const retryOriginalRequest = new Promise(resolve => {
            addSubscriber(newToken => {
                response.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + newToken;
                resolve(axios(response.config));
            });
        });

        // There are no fetchint token request and the access token is expired (no length)
        if (!isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken && accessToken === "") {
            isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = true;

            const response = await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: `${baseURL}/v1/oauth2/token`,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
                },
                data: qs.stringify({
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
                }),
                auth: {
                    username: "your paypal client id",
                    password: "your paypal secret id"
                }
            });

            // An error happened when asking for a new token
            if (!response.data) {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }

            const newToken = response.data.access_token;

            // Store generated token in db for a next usage
            tokenUtils.saveToken(newToken);

            isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false;
            onAccessTokenFetched(newToken);
        }

        return retryOriginalRequest;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}
```

I commented the whole code, hoping to be much clear as possible, feel free to ask any question eventually.
Essentially, a failed request is added to the `subscribers` which is handled by the following:

```
let subscribers = [];

function addSubscriber(callback) {
    subscribers.push(callback);
}
```

each subscribed `request` is execute after the token generation by:

```
function onAccessTokenFetched(accessToken) {
    subscribers.forEach(callback => callback(accessToken));
    subscribers = [];
}
```

So an `API` request will look like this:

```
instance.get(
    `${baseURL}/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-0SUB6KG4203B`)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error');
        return null;
    });
```

I also have a `tokenUtils` which contains two function:

- getAccessToken: get the token stored from a database
- storeAccessToken: store a token to the db

I've also uploaded the full code [here](https://gofile.io/?c=gF6OVG), you may take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General Thoughts

I haven't used the paypal API before but did obtain credentials and ran the code. I don't see much that would improve the logic to fetch the token but do see small improvements that can be made.

### Review

A common convention is to have constants in `ALL_CAPS` - so `baseURL` can be converted to `BASE_URL` E.g. per [Google JS style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-constant-names), [airbnb style guide](https://airbnb.io/javascript/#naming--uppercase). While it isn't totally immutable unless frozen it signifies to readers that it should not be modified.

For more information on the topic, see [the MDN documentation about constants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Constants), as well as answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40291766/1575353).

A more appropriate name than `isTokenExpiredError` would be `isResponseUnauthenticated` since the 401 error means "*Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials.*"<sup>[1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-responses/#http-status-codes)</sup>

> ```
> return (errorResponse.status == 401) ? true : false;
> ```

This is overly verbose - it could be simplified to:

```
return (errorResponse.status == 401)
```

There is only one usage of `errorResponse` after it is assigned - it can be eliminated by substituting `error.response` in the one place it is used.

The variable `subscribers` could be truncated with [`.length = 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) in `onAccessTokenFetched()` and then be declared with `const` because it wouldn't be re-assigned. This helps avoid accidental re-assignment in the future when the code is expanded.

The request made with `axios()` to get the token could be simplified using [`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config)

```
const response = await axios.post(`${baseURL}/v1/oauth2/token`, data, {...})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just have some questions:
1. Should be all the constants `ALL_CAPS`? Even those inside the methods?
2. Could you suggest a specific folder name convention where I can add this `Axios` interceptors?

Comment: 1. I would only use that for hard-coded values, which likely won’t change ever, and not other variables even if they shouldn’t be reassigned - e.g. an array like `subscribers`. 2. You could make a wrapper that returns/exports `axios` Or `instance`- maybe call it `axios-instance`, `axios-wrapper` or something similar

Comment: Thansk for your suggests I've appreciated